# How to compute complex line integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, parametric

I am wondering how to compute the line integral of

$$
\mathrm{g}\left(z\right) = z\left(z^{\ast}\right)^{2} - \cos\left(z\right)\quad
\mbox{over the curve}\quad 
\,\mathrm{y}\left(t\right) = \cos\left(2t\right ) + \sin\left(2t\right)\,\mathrm{i}\,,\quad 0 \leq t \leq {\pi \over 2}
$$
where $z^{\ast}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$.

I am given that the answer is
$\pi\mathrm{i} + \sin\left(1\right) - \sin\left(1\right)$

$$
\mbox{What I tried, I tried noting that the  integral can be }\quad
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\mathrm{g}\left(\mathrm{y}\left(t\right)\right)\,\mathrm{y}'\left(t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
where
$\,\mathrm{g}\left(\mathrm{y}\left(t\right)\right) =
\mathrm{e}^{-2\mathrm{i}t} - \cos\left(\mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}t}\right)\quad\mbox{and where}\quad \mathrm{y}'\left(t\right) = -2\sin\left(2t\right) + 2\cos\left(2t\right)\mathrm{i}$.

But then I get stuck on computing next, because I have so many terms multiplying , some containg i and some not, some containing exponentials, setc, so I dont know how to proceed, is there something I  am missing? Or can anyone help show me how the answer was gotten? Is this on the right track?

Thanks

Comment: 1. What curve is parametrised by $y$? 2. Note that $z(z^{\ast})^2 = \dfrac{\lvert z\rvert^4}{z}$. 3. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus for holomorphic functions.

Comment: The curve is the the top semi circle

Comment: Good. Then how does point 2 help here?

Comment: Since we can write it not contain conjugate we have that it is holomorphic so we can use FTC, but Im having trouble understanding how to integrate that with the modulus

Comment: What can you say about $\lvert z\rvert$ on the curve?

Comment: I belive that it would be equal to 1

Comment: Right. So can you rewrite the integral in the form $\int_{\Gamma} f(z)\,dz$ with a holomorphic (on a neighbourhood of the curve) $f$?

Comment: Hm, im not exactly sure I understand that part. If I do it like that then would my integral be ln(z)? in which case I dont get the answer given

Comment: That's only part of it, don't forget the $\cos z$ part of $g$.

Comment: Right if I included that I would have ln(z)-sin(z) evaluated from -1 to 1

Comment: Why $0$ and $\pi$? What are the endpoints of the curve?

Comment: Wow, got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The answer is $2\sin\left(1\right) + \pi\mathrm{i}$. So, you have a $\large -$ sign which must be a $\large +$ sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
z & = \expo{2\ic t}\implies
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{g}\pars{z}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\expo{-2\ic t} - \cos\pars{\expo{2\ic t}}}
\\
\ds{\totald{z}{t}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\expo{2\ic t}\pars{2\ic}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
The integral becomes:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bracks{\expo{-2\ic t} - \cos\pars{\expo{2\ic t}}}
\bracks{\expo{2\ic t}\pars{2\ic}}\,\dd t =
2\ic\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\,\dd t - \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{\expo{2\ic t}}
\bracks{\expo{2\ic t}\pars{2\ic}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
2\ic\,{\pi \over 2} - \bracks{\sin\pars{\expo{2\ic t}}}_{\ 0}^{\ \pi/2} =
\pi\ic - \sin\pars{-1} + \sin\pars{1} =
\bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{\ds{2\sin\pars{1} + \pi\ic}}
\end{align}